# Connecting Mysql with Android

Tags: android, mysql

I am new for Android Development. Now I want to connect Mysql with Android Application for uploading data to the server. Please send any sample code for connecting mysql with Android.

Comment: This can be closed as "too broad".

Answer (score 3):

There is no MySQL connection library for Android that I'm aware of, unless you can get the MySQL java library operational under Android.

Either way, you don't want to do this - that would mean exposing your MySQL server to the world for TCP connections. There's no way to tell what IP your device will be appearing from. Each mobile carrier has their own internet gateway for devices, and it's invariably a NAT firewall to boot. This would be require you to leave MySQL wide open to TCP connections from all IPs, a major security hole.

Instead, you should build up a web service that acts as a middleman between your app and MySQL.

Comment: +1 for some sort of 'middleman' - it could be a web service although anything which requires some credentials and prevents direct access would suffice IMO

Answer (score 3):

You can use MySql to connect to your android application through a servlet using Apache Tomcat. You will have to put your SQL syntax into the servlet you created and in your Java insert the URI path for the servlet.

Answer (score 3):

i believe you need apache tomcat to run a servlet for your sql, do you have it?

Answer (score 1):

The way it should work is , you use the sql-lite database to store the data that is generated in your application.Then, when you have a fixed set of data,convert into a protocol buffer, transmit the same via web-services,depacket it and store into a mysql database at the server.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to manage data in a private database, use the `android.database.sqlite` classes.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if android supports mysql.

Go through the Notepad Tutorial for information on connecting to sqllite

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Other than `sqlite` we can't connect with any other database.
Using sqlite is also not a good practice, better use web service calls.
It is because, some viewers will be having less memory phones, has we are doing the application global, we should think of these things.
For small requirements you can use sqlite.